# Eclipse package vs. Eclipse folder, в чём разница?

Tags: eclipse, package

Доброго времени суток.

Давно не даёт покоя вопрос, периодически возникающий при работе над проектами.

В чём разница между Eclipse package и Eclipse folder.

Я понимаю, что структурно в дереве каталогов разницы никакой. Но, Eclipse же каким-то образом различает в Package Explorer, что вот это packages, их нужно отображать другой иконкой, их можно показывать во Flat виде, для них можно приводить путь к укороченному виду, в отличие от folders, которые отображаются другой иконкой и для них отображается вся последовательная структура каталогов.

Как Eclipse понимает что между ними есть разница?
Где он хранит настройки для понимания различия?
Можно ли настроить значение пакета вручную где-то в конфиг-файлах или в настройках Eclipse?

Вопрос возник после переноса проекта из другой IDE, и после переноса часть директорий проекта находящаяся в директории test, не получила статус package, что привело к ошибке в классах с указанием пакета.
Т.е. вся структура директорий соответствует структуре нужных пакетов, но, без отметки что эти директории являются пакетами классы выдают ошибки.

Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 0):

Если кому-нибудь когда-нибудь понадобится.

Ответ был получен в англоязычной части stackoverflow - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58314933/eclipse-package-vs-eclipse-folder-what-is-the-difference